# combined product page and checkout page

Tags: product, checkout, ce-1.9.0.1

I'm working on a charity/non-profit site and was considering making some customizations that would combine the product page with the checkout page. An example on an existing charity site can be found here:https://secure3.4agoodcause.com/project-cure/gift.aspx?id=1 . Since the only products on the whole store will be virtual products for making a donation, it's unlikely a customer will want to continue to "shop around" before completing their donation, so it makes sense to put it all on one page. Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: interesting question, I'd be glad to see it answered.

Comment: question is interesting, but it is too broad.

Comment: Either you do this via AJAX and clone all the behavior from magento's checkout or you implement your own controller, cloning all the behaviour.


I think the easiest approach is to use some one page checkout, add the product via AJAX and remove the check for anything in cart and just show all the time the checkout page.


Beside this, I would recommend to **NOT use magento** for this project. It is far too simple and magento far too complex. to

Comment: You should maybe consider using a WordPress with a module (I'm pretty sure some modules can do that), it would be far easier than using a Magento for what you require.

Comment: still getting the hang of stack exchange...but thanks to all who provided input! I suspected Magento might be a bit much for this purpose, but we already have 7 other sites running on it, so I continued with what I am used to. I'll look into WordPress though. Thanks.